# how to get the index of the treeview child node?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How do I get the index of a child node of a parent node? My treeview is like this:

- Root node 1

  - Node 1
  - Node 2
- Root node 2

  - Node 1
  - Node 2
- Root node 3

  - Node 1
  - Node 2

For example I want to get the child node index of Root node 2, how do I do that?

```
'Imports System.Windows.Forms

Private Sub trv1_AfterSelect(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles trv1.AfterSelect
    Dim a As Integer
    x = e.Node.Index
    debug.print x
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you explain how your example code relates to your question? If all you need is the index in a tree view (no user interaction needed), you do not need any event handler (triggered by user interaction).

Comment: That aside, there's an unused local variable `a` in your code. Shouldn't you declare `x` instead?

Comment: what i want to know is  how do i determine which node1 it belongs? does it belong to root node 1 or root node 2 so on.... my idea is to get the index of the nodes but index of the child node is thesame with the root node.

Comment: Please don't ask your *actual* question in a comment; not everyone might read all comments before they answer. Instead, please edit your question. This improves your chances that you will receive an answer to your actual question.

Comment: that is already my question i just rephrased it

Comment: "child node index of Root node 2" is logically inconsistent, a root node isn't a child of any parent node.  Very unclear why TreeNode.Index isn't good enough.  If you need to uniquely identify any node then its index is useless, its starts numbering back at 0 for the children.  A tree, not an array.  Consider using its Name.

Comment: @Ron: If you've seen the typo in your question, why don't you fix it by editing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I've got my work around instead of getting the index of the child node of a selected parent node i'm doing it in-reverse i will get the parent index of the selected child now. and expound the code from below

```
Private Sub treeView1_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles treeView1.AfterSelect

If (e.Node.Parent IsNot Nothing) 
  If (e.Node.Parent.GetType() Is GetType(TreeNode)) Then
     label1.Text = "Parent: " + e.Node.Parent.Text + _
       ControlChars.Cr + "Parent Index: " + e.Node.Parent.Index.ToString()
  End If 
Else
  label1.Text = "No parent node." 
End If
```

End Sub